# A Program Reports Maximum Thread Count Reached RLIMIT_NPROC, Despite Actual Thread Count Being Way Below Limit

Tags: thumbnails, totem

I encountered a strange problem with thumbnail generation in Nautilus. I noticed that the totem-video-thumbnailer was not working correctly and it was consuming so much CPU, so I attempted to manually generate a thumbnail for one of my .mp3 files. However, I received the following error message:

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 6 of 8: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 30714 current, 30714 max
```

As far as I understand, this error message suggests that the number of created threads in the OS has reached its maximum limit, but upon running the top command and pressing H, I see that only 1,200 threads are currently running on the system. Furthermore, I am able to run other programs without issue. Why then is the totem-video-thumbnailer reporting that the maximum number of created threads has been reached? This problem can be solved by setting a global env (i.e. OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4) but I am curious about the reason.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52026652/openblas-blas-thread-init-pthread-create-resource-temporarily-unavailable) answer your questions?